# What is the name of the language in which the main program of Chromium is written?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

We would like to develop a new plugin for Chromium.

To achieve this goal, we must learn at least one computer language.

We do not know its / their name(s).

Do you know the name of the computer language in which is written the program
contains

1) the variable whose value at time t is the URL to which the resources of the Chromium browser of mister X is connected at time t;

2) the variable whose value at time t is the text resources to which the Chromium browser of mister X is connected at time t.

Assembly?
C?
C ++?
Java?
Python?

Do you know how to find the names of these variables in the source code of Chromium ? With documentation designed by the developers of this software ?

Thank you very much.

Sincerely,
Naomi and Sophie

Comment: Although Chromium is written in C++, you can probably write an extension for it in JavaScript, which will be easier. Look for a tutorial about writing Chrome extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chromium is written in C++. Currently, C++11 and C++14 are supported. The following is mentioned in the Chromium C++ Style Guide:

> - **C++11:** Default allowed; see banned features below
> - **C++14:** Default allowed; see banned features below
> - **C++17:** Not yet supported in Chromium, unlikely before mid-2021; tracking bug
> - **C++20:** Not yet standardized
> - **Abseil:** Initially supported July 31, 2020; see allowed/banned/TBD features below
>
>   - absl::StatusOr: Initially supported September 3, 2020

The C++ Style Guide is included in in the source on [https://chromium.googlecode.com](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/):

- [Chromium C++ Style Guide in Git](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/styleguide/c++/c++11.html)
- [Chromium C++ Style Guide in HTML](https://chromium-cpp.appspot.com/)

Comment: hate to be picky but this does doesnt answer the multiple questions asked. questions like this should be closed not answered.

Comment: Should there be some votes for closure and the question put `[on hold]` or `[closed]` then? I've seen other questions in those states.

Comment: true, but hard since being at negative score most people wont see it. did manage to get 3 close votes so far.

Comment: @Grokify Wow its amazing if Chrome is written in c++.I have studied c++ from first semester and then in oop and in data structures and algorithms and still I didnt gave importance to the language because I was thinking that c++ is old now and c# ,java and javascript are now the languages to master but this amazed to me that such a big software is using c++.Now I will study it with interest again.Please let me know that on which IDE or platform i.e visual studio or any other IDE they have used for its development.I am interested to know about that.Thanks